# How to get Particular versions of GoogleApps Admin Directory jars

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-settings-api

When we are developing a client for googleapps using the admin sdk we started using the

**google-api-services-admin-directory_v1-rev35-1.18.0-rc.jar** and its dependency jars like google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar,google-api-services-admin-directory_v1-rev35-1.18.0-rc.jar,httpclient-4.0.1.jar,etc.,

but now we can see that there is a latest admin directory jar one on the googleapps download link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/ 
I also tried getting the jar from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ and downloaded google-api-java-client-featured.zip and couldn't find the **admin directory jar.**

Are the latest ones are backward compatible? 
if we are replacing the admin jar to latest in our client everytime then we also need to take use of all its dependency jars as latest??
Is there any location to get the particular versions of admin directory jars?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of the client libraries are usually backwards compatible, assuming the API version (v1) is the same. You should also update the dependencies, assuming they have changed. Unless there is a new feature in the Admin SDK or client library you wish to use, it's probably best to stick with your current setup.